# Scotchbox: Document root missing / desynced with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, virtualenv, virtualhost

I'm using Scotchbox (box.scotch.io) for Vagrant. Since their last update I get a document root missing error (*AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/mypage] does not exist*) when i try and set up my some domain configs in Apache. I can't really determine whether its a change in settings since Scotch 2.0 or if Vagrant for some reason has descyned these folders. My setup as follows,

Vagrant file pathway

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

Apache domain config pathway

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mypage.dev
        ServerAlias www.mypage.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mypage
</VirtualHost>
```

The 000-default and scotchbox config files both point to /var/www/public. My default dev folder is located at ~username/Development, in that folder is my Vagrant file.
Any ideas?
Let me know if I need to provide other details.

Update: Switching to Docker. Tired of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just cloned `Scotchbox` and my `Vagrant` file also contains:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

My apache config (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`) looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have `public` directory in my root dir on the host machine, `ls -1` prints:

```
README.md
Vagrantfile
public
```

**And it works for me!**

In your case, you need update apache config, and have:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public
```

And pay attention that you have `public` directory near `Vagrantfile`.

If you have directory `mypage` - then run `mv mypage public`